# ConstraintLayout - Constraint to the nearest View

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

First of all, sorry for the quite generic title but I couldn't find a way to explain it properly.

I can't figure out how to make a View grow until it finds another View on its way. Basically, I have a View_A constrainted to the bottom-right of its parent, that can indefinitely grow to the left, and I'd like the Views above it to grow vertically, taking all the available space, but only if View_A doesn't get in their way, like in the pictures.

[Situation 1 - Tall Views can grow indefinitely](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PUo3e.png)

[Situation 2 - Tall Views should behave like this when View_A is on their way](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vECUo.png)

Basically, I'd like the bottom constraint of the tall Views to change automatically from parent to top of View_A based on View_A's width, but I don't know if this can be done with ConstraintLayout out of the box.

Comment: You would have to do this programmatically by either changing the constraints or setting the bottom margin of the tall view.

Comment: Yes I'm pretty sure this can't be done out of the box.

Comment: Thank you! Yes, doing it programmatically was my last resource - but at least now I know I'm not being dumb :)